# Access to nested methods when DSL

Tags: ruby, dsl

```
class Warcraft 

  def initialize &block
    instance_eval &block
  end

  def method_missing name, *args, &block
    instance_variable_set("@#{name}".to_sym, args[0])
    self.class.send(:define_method, name, proc { instance_variable_get("@#{name}")})
  end

  def game &block
    @game = Game.new &block
  end

  class Game 
    def initialize &block
      instance_eval &block
    end

    def method_missing name, *args, &block
      instance_variable_set("@#{name}".to_sym, args[0])
      self.class.send(:define_method, name, proc { instance_variable_get("@#{name}")})
    end   
  end

end

warcraft = Warcraft.new do
  name "Warcraft III"
  battle_net :iccup

  game do
    side :sentinels
    hero "Furion"
    rune_appear_every 2
  end
end

puts warcraft.inspect # => #<Warcraft:0x00000000be3e80 @name="Warcraft III", @battle_net=:iccup, @game=#<Warcraft::Game:0x000000009c6c38 @side=:sentinels, @hero="Furion", @rune_appear_every=2>>
```

How to access nested methods?

```
puts warcraft.battle_net # => iccup
puts warcraft.side #=> #<Proc:0x000000010de6d8@dsl.rb:9 (lambda)>
puts warcraft.game #=> dsl.rb:18:in `instance_eval': block not supplied (ArgumentError)
puts warcraft.game.side #=> dsl.rb:18:in `instance_eval': block not supplied (ArgumentError)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`puts warcraft.game` throws an error because your `Warcraft#game` method requires a block and you are calling it like an attribute accessor.

I'm not sure exactly what you need here but if you want to use the `Warcraft#game` method to get the current game as well as set up a new game then you could just return the current game if a block is not given, something like this:

```
def game &block
  if block_given?
    @game = Game.new &block
  else
    @game
  end
end
```